# Dynamic User Input Forms

Tags: java, android, dynamic, input

I want to collect information about the user. Let's say, I want to collect information like age and gender for each of their family members.

How could I do this, in a form, given I do not know their family size, so that when prompted, they can input the number of family members. To which a screen now shows, a form like list with family member 1:
Age:
Gender:
Family Member 2:
Age
Gender
and so on. I would like one big list, so you could scroll down the app to input all information. And a submit button at the end will submit the form to me. I just don't know how to handle the unknown number of editText forms etc and how to then extract the info from each.

If you could show me how to do this with some code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is Many Different Way
I will mention one of them:

-Start by have a Layout of EditText and a button. For Size of family Question
-Layout with only a ViewPager
-Layout for Fragement, How u want the form to look like For example 2 EditText (Age and Gender) and 1 Button

-Create a Fragment.Java class and inflate the Fragment layout inside it

Now on you main activity set the first layout with the size of family layout.

for Example he enters 4.

now open a new activity with the ViewPager layout as its Content.

```
 int size = 4;
 ArrayList<Fragments> lf = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
```

Create the fragments with a loop

```
for(int count;0 count<size; count ++){

    Fragment f = new Fragment();
    lf.add(f);
}
```

Now create the PagerAdapter passing the "lf" to it

you can set Text for every button accordingly

```
String Text;
if(pagenumber == size-1) //means last page
  text= "finish";
else
   text = "next";
```

then

```
button.setText(text);
```

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION**

1. FirstFragment.xml should have what you want in the form (2 EditTexts and 1 Button)
2. main_pager.xml has only ViewPager
3. Create Your mainActivity.java Class with `setContentView(R.layout.main_Pager);`
4. In your onCreate() You find your viewPager and give to a ViewPager Instance.
5. After that do the above loop as i explained according to size of family
6. now call setAdapter on the ViewPager . 
   ex:   `vPager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(), lf));`
7. Here is your FragmentAdapter Class.

   ```
   public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
         private List<Fragment> fragments;

         public FragmentAdapter (FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
             super(fm);
                 this.fragments = fragments;
         }

         @Override
         public Fragment getItem(int position) {
             return this.fragments.get(position);
         }

         @Override
         public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
         {
             super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
         }

         @Override
         public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
         }
    }
   ```

Comment: Hello Mo Adel, Thank you for your help! I just need a few things clarified. So I've created all the layouts and a FirstFragment.java file which has inflated the ViewPager layout. I have an activity which receives from the user, the number of family members however, I'm a little confused with the fragment looping, and create the PagerAdapter passing lf to it. So if I have a FirstFragment.java file, what should be in my FirstFragment.java file so I can loop through the fragments. And extract thedata?

Comment: Thanks for the update however, I've made my FragmentAdapter as you've stated. Do I put that loop etc in the onCreate() of my mainactivity.java class? I'm get just getting a few errors with vPager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(), lf)); This line of code. Also with the giving to an instance, how exactly do I do that? I'm sorry, I am very new to this. And this particular situation is really annoying me. Would you perhaps like to assist me through email or something? I'm really sorry but I would love to clear this up! Thank you for your help.

Comment: regarding your first question, yes you have to add it to you onCreate in MainActivity.java . can you let me know what errors are coming up for vPager.setAd......

Comment: So when I copy your FragmentAdaptor class I get this error Implicit super constructor FragmentPagerAdapter() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor on the class declaration. It then complains about super(fm); not being the first line in the constructor however, I'm pretty sure it is. In the ArrayList line, should both ArrayList<Fragments> lf .... ArrayList<Fragment> have "Fragment" and not one with plural? The vPager.set .. gives the error "The constructor FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager, ArrayList<Fragment>) is undefined". Thanks for your help yet again

Comment: ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        vp.setAdapter(null); Is that how I should find my viewPager and give it to a ViewPager instance? Now does all the stuff actually have to be in "MainActivity" as I already have a main activity doing other stuff. I'm using another activity to call all this, which I've called FirstFragment.java but yeah, I'm pretty sure it's the same principle. I only want the fragments to appear when I'm collecting this data, elsewhere from my MainActivity. Did you have an email address, so I could send you my current code for you to help further?

Comment: Fragment Adapter has to be in a file of its own, FragmentAdapter.java and i corrected something in FragmentAdapter code. Please try the new one i updated. It shold work now

Comment: It is in a file of it's own... exactly like that! Which is confusing me. I tried your edited code and I get "Implicit super constructor FragmentPagerAdapter() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor" for the first line About FragmentAdapter in it's class declaration. And still it's saying super is not the first line, after it asked me to make public TestFragmentAdapter of return type void.

Comment: replace TestFragmentAdapter with FragmentAdapter

Comment: This line is still giving me a problem: "vp.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter(getFragmentManager(), lf));" where         ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        vp.setAdapter(null);  It is stating that "Syntax error on token "setAdapter", = expected after this token" Now, I know null should not be vp.setAdapter, so how do I pass the instance? I'm really not sure. So if you could help with that. And I think it'll be alright. That's my only error at the moment. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay, if you can, please email me at "macosoccerstar@hotmail.com"; it's complaining about a long discussion. But I think the issue is two different "FragmentAdapter" classes, with different sets of arguments. So when I use that line, I guess it doesn't feel its defined? I think. So how could I alter that FragmentAdaptor.java file in order to fix this issue. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you can zip u project and email it to m.adel88@hotmail.com and I will have a look it

Comment: You forgot to attach you project to the email

Comment: It's been resent with the attachment!

Comment: Replied with 2 emails.

Comment: Absolute legend, with amazing help! Really went over and above. I appreciate it.